# How can I get the size of a TemporaryFile in python?

Tags: python

Currently when I write to a temporary:

```
import tempfile
a = tempfile.TemporaryFile()

a.write(...)

# The only way I know to get the size
a.seek(0)
len(a.read())
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Not a duplicate, the other question asks about a regular file not temporary file which has no path.

Comment: the already-answered stackoverflow thread does not have any solution related to  temporary files (especially `SpooledTemporaryFile`), this post should be reopened

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
import tempfile
f = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
f.write('abcd')
f.tell()
# 4
```

> `f.tell()` returns an integer giving the file object’s current position in the file represented as number of bytes from the beginning of the file when in binary mode and an opaque number when in text mode.

If you are jumping around the file with seek, then seek to the end of the file first with:
`a.seek(0, 2)` the second parameter "whence"=2 means the position is relative to the end of the file.

https://docs.python.org/3.11/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Answer (score 12):

You can use `os.stat` assuming the file has either been closed or all pending writes have been flushed

```
os.stat(a.name).st_size
```